# Add registration form to JAAS protected servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, jaas

For my Java web application I am using JAAS for authentication and authorization. Anything is protected, but the login and error page, thus I configured my Jetty with:

```
ConstraintMapping cm = new ConstraintMapping();
cm.setConstraint(constraint);
cm.setPathSpec("/*");
```

Now I would like to offer a sign up page, is there a way to define an exception for the path spec? Regular expression do not work here as far as I have tested and seen in the source code.

Comment: why don't you have your constraints in the deployment descriptor?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy You mean defined it in Jetty XML? What difference does it make? It should be the same.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Yes, the XML defined in `web.xml` is Jetty XML, anyway it doesn't make any difference whether I configure it in a `web.xml` or programmatically in the Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with **constraint relaxation**.
You can add another constraint to your constraint mapping, which will relax the more general constraint for `/*`:

```
Constraint relaxation = new Constraint();
relaxation.setName(Constraint.ANY_ROLE);
relaxation.setAuthenticate(false);

ConstraintMapping rm = new ConstraintMapping();
rm.setConstraint(relaxation);
rm.setPathSpec("/signup");
```

Then you add this constraint as well to your `ContextSecurityHandler`

```
csh.addConstraintMapping(rm);
```